# Python not found when running `where python` on macOS Monterey 12.4 while `where python3` works

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run `where python` in the terminal I get back:

```
python not found
```

But when I run `where python3` I get back:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

How do I fix the path, do I need to reinstall python or create a Symlink?

Comment: I add this in my ~/.bash_profile: `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you can make an alias :

```
alias python=python3
```

Adding this line into ~/.bashrc will run python3 when you call python.

You'll just need to run :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

for this to take effect.

**OR**

Install python2 from python.org : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/